# Can I get\download the traffic flow data of a specific date and time?

Tags: here-api, here-traffic

Is there a way to get the traffic flow data of a specific date and time?

For example, the below request gives real-time traffic data.

[https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?bbox=29.6890%2C-95.4008%3B29.7165%2C-95.5007&apiKey={API_KEY}](https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?bbox=29.6890%2C-95.4008%3B29.7165%2C-95.5007&apiKey=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

How can I specify date-time here? Thanks.

Comment: As documented, HERE Traffic API supports only real time traffic only and historical data is not supported. However, if there are any specific use cases then you could contact here tech support to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

HERE provides several ways to get the historical traffic information:

1. Get the Traffic Pattern from HERE Map Content catalog
   https://developer.here.com/documentation/here-map-content/dev_guide/topics-attributes/traffic-pattern-attributes.html
2. Get the Traffic Pattern from Mobile SDK
   https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.19/dev_guide/topics/traffic-history.html
3. Get the Traffic Pattern and Speed from HERE Map Attributes API with TRAFFIC_PATTERN_FC* layers and TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FC* layers.
   https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html